# why I can't delete my post?

Tags: support, deletion

why i can't delete my answer into

[PEG-silane treatment: why incubate for 18 hours at 60 degrees Celsius?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7980/peg-silane-treatment-why-incubate-for-18-hours-at-60-degrees-celsius/7982#7982)

I tryed several times, but the system doesn't answer ...
Who can help me?

Thanks in advance

Viola

Comment: That answer has been deleted 30 minutes ago

Comment: at the bottom of my answer, i found: deleted by kmm♦ 44 mins ago - *Why was your post deleted? See the faq* - But i found also a comment that said that my answer "has nothing to do with the question". I know that most of people are chemists, biologists, and technical people. I'm not. But I have some knowledge, experience and a lot of knowledge of the biology of nature and animals. So sometimes I think I can answer. But no. Then sorry. I deleted myself.

Answer (score 2):

As Mad Scientist points out, that answer was deleted by kmn before you posted this meta question.

If I had to guess as to what might have happened, perhaps you had not refreshed your browser page to see that it had been deleted, meaning the delete link didn't work for you as you can't un-delete content deleted by community moderators.

Comment: I tried to delete it 4-5 times before to ask in meta. So I guess we superimposed. Sorry for all so much annoying you.